# Error when using test_client (Flask) - raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)

Tags: python, flask, pytest

flask application code:

```
# main.py 
from flask import Flask, Response
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def post_example():
    return Response("aaa")
```

and this is my testing code:

```
# e2e.py
from main import app

test_client = app.test_client()


def test_flask_api_call():
    response = test_client.post("/", {"a": "b"})
    pass
```

I keep receiving:

```
raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: '://%7B%27a%27:%20%27b%27%7D/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on the `post` method call. You have to name your **data** arguments `client.post("/", data={"a": "b"})`, if it's not the case it is considered as a part of the URL.

```py
urllib.parse.quote("/" + str({"a": "b"}))
# '/%7B%27a%27%3A%20%27b%27%7D'
```

Here is the test code rewritten to define a `fixture` for the client initialization. More info on testing flask application on the [official doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/).

```py
import pytest

from main import app


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def client():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


def test_flask_api_call(client):
    response = client.post("/", data={"a": "b"})
    assert response.status_code == 200, f"Got bad status code {response.status_code}"
```